# Java - Ftp Upload Error

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol - this is the error i am getting when i run this code:

```
  package ftp.upload;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FtpUpload {
public static void main(String[] args) {
/* line 14 */    FtpClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        client.connect("test.info");
        client.login("test", "test");

        //
        // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        //
        String filename = "Touch.dat";
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

        //
        // Store file to server
        //
        client.storeFile(filename, fis);
        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

that is the code for my ftp upload the error is on line 14

thanks for the help

Comment: Please add a comment showing where line 14 is and post your full compiler error message

Comment: ok i will edit my post :)

Comment: so i did not import it i will try importing it

Comment: Where is FtpClient class? It needs to be imported, if not in same package.

Comment: when i import it i get alot of other errors

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: FTPClient.<init>

Comment: Sounds like FtpClient doesn't have an empty constructor (like the one you're trying to use)?

Comment: `FtpClient client = new FTPClient()` should be `FTPClient client = new FTPClient()` (note the uppercase `FTP`)... My advice: use an IDE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your compiler doesn't know what FTPClient is.

Download this commons-net.jar file from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi)

Add a import to FTPClient

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
```

Also there's a typo on your code,

```
FtpClient client = new FTPClient();
```

but it should be

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

Also have a look at [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for FTPClient documentation.

Comment: i am getting this error java.io.FileNotFoundException: Touch.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Hi Ben, this isn't related to this question, can you please create a new question with your new issue and the exception? :)